# Problem using a font from newtxmath

Tags: fonts, newtxmath

I'm trying to set up my preferred mix of fonts from `mathptmx` and `newtxmath`. This would require using the `largsymbols` font from `newtxmath`, since I like its integrals better than those from `mathptmx`. However, this one font just won't load. Here is a simple snippet illustrating the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{ntxex}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
$\forall\exists<>\leq\geq\int\subseteq\supseteq$
\[\int abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+-=\alpha\]
\end{document}
```

Result with `pdfTeX`:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./newtxtest2.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(./newtxtest2.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMX/ntxex/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMX/cmex/m/n' instead on input line 5.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./newtxtest2.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 )</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb
></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></
usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on newtxtest2.pdf (1 page, 37359 bytes).
SyncTeX written on newtxtest2.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on newtxtest2.log.
```

[image]

Same goes for `XeLaTeX`. Now, in a more complicated situation with a package of mine, I got an error. In this case, I get a warning, and the wrong shape for the integral: I get the Computer Modern one, the default one, if I read that `cmex` correctly. Indeed, adding

```
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{ntxex}{b}{n}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{OMX}{ntxex}{m}{n}
```

produces, with `XeLaTeX`:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./newtxtest2.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(./newtxtest2.aux)
No file OMXntxex.fd.

./newtxtest2.tex:6: LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \begin{document}
```

Yet the code is copied literally from the package, so what is going on here? Why is that `.fd` not found? I know where it is, but `TeX` seems not to, and if I put it where `TeX` can find it, it starts doing strange things and calling `metafont` and ending up with no `.tfm`:

```
[…]
kpathsea: Running mktextfm bickham-r
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input bickham-r
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf bickham-r

! I can't find file `bickham-r'.
<*> ...jfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input bickham-r

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
```

Why is this coming about? How do I get the desired shape for the integral symbol without loading `newtxmath` directly?

Comment: There is no such file. Hence, it cannot be found. ***Which*** package did you copy those lines from? Certainly not `newtxmath.sty`.

Comment: There is no OMX encoded font `ntxex`. The `newtxmath` package uses a different encoding for the math extension font called LMX.

Comment: Note that the equivalent of the `.fd` file for the `LMX` encoding and the setup of that encoding are part of `newtxmath.sty`. So you cannot use those lines on their own substituting `LMX` either.

Comment: 1) I have _found_ the `.fd` file with `newtxmath.sty`, in the same directory I mean; 2) `newtxmath.sty` has _precisely_ that line on my HD; 3) Indeed I tried `LMX` and it didn't work.

Comment: What does [this piece of `newtxmath.sty`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0qkpJ.png) say now?

Comment: Those lines are not in the copy of `newtxmath.sty` which I have.

Comment: Curious. Has that package been changed since the last TeXLive release? I should be up-to-date up to that time.

Comment: I'm using the frozen TL 2014 release. That is, I've updated TL 2014 as far as possible but that's it. Note that the string `ntxexv` does not occur in my copy of `newtxmath.sty` at all. (I know you're not using it but it is in the snippet you showed.)

Comment: What does your `newtxmath` say instead of what I have?

Comment: @MickG Are you using pretest? The package has been updated since the freeze. I have the set up of the `LMX` encoding etc.

Comment: So you have what you put in your answer?

Comment: No. Not quite. Hang on a minute... [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6mI5F.png) is what I have. But the package has since been updated with changes to the maths extension configuration (according to the readme on CTAN). So if you are using pretest, you very likely have something different. What is the date of the file you have? EDIT: v. 1.434 2015/04/07.

Comment: `\def\fileversion{1.11}
\def\filedate{2013/05/25}
\ProvidesPackage{newtxmath}
 [\filedate\space v\fileversion]`

Comment: However, the [updated version on CTAN](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YaVFE.png) has the same as mine, even though it is a newer version...

Comment: @MickG That is old... You're not using TeX Live 2014?

Comment: Whoops, wrong directory, I have `\def\fileversion{1.27}
\def\filedate{2014/04/26}` and the same as you for `largesymbols`. I have two distributions on my computer and copied code from the wrong one accidentally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you don't need scaling, at a minimum you need something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
  \DeclareFontEncoding{LMX}{}{}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
  \DeclareFontFamily{LMX}{ntxexx}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}{<->ntxexx}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{LMX}{ntxexx}{b}{n}{<->ntxbexx}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{LMX}{ntxexx}{bx}{n}{<->ssub ntxexx/b/n}{}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{LMX}{ntxexx}{b}{n}
\begin{document}
  $\forall\exists<>\leq\geq\int\subseteq\supseteq$
  \[\int abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+-=\alpha\]
\end{document}
```

[image: mismash]

However, if you only want to use a couple of symbols from the font, this is not a good way to do it (because everything which uses `largesymbols` will now use the `newtxmath` fonts) and it won't work properly anyway (because `LMX` is not equivalent to `OMX`).

So it is better to create a new symbol font and use that just to redefine the symbols you want (as [egreg's answer does](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239507/)).

You might, however, also want to use the integral symbols for maths extension A from `newtxmath`. In that case, you need to set up an additional font, but this configuration can be taken straight from `newtxmath.sty` since it already defines an additional symbol font.

Putting this together:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LMX}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMX}{ntxexx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}{<->ntxexx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMX}{ntxexx}{b}{n}{<->ntxbexx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMX}{ntxexx}{bx}{n}{<->ssub ntxexx/b/n}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsTX}{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbolsTX}{bold}{LMX}{ntxexx}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTX}{"52}
    \def\int{\intop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTX}{"48}
    \def\oint{\ointop\nolimits}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsTXA}{U}{ntxexa}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbolsTXA}{bold}{U}{ntxexa}{b}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{ntxexa}{m}{n}
\def\re@DeclareMathSymbol#1#2#3#4{%
  \let#1=\undefined
  \DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{8}
\def\oiint{\oiintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\ointctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{10}
\def\ointctrclockwise{\ointctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\ointclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{12}
\def\ointclockwise{\ointclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\sqintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{14}
\def\sqint{\sqintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{33}
\def\iint{\iintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{35}
\def\iiint{\iiintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iiiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{37}
\def\iiiint{\iiiintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\idotsintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{39}
\def\idotsint{\idotsintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{41}
\def\oiiint{\oiiintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varointctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{43}
\def\varointctrclockwise{\varointctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varointclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{45}
\def\varointclockwise{\varointclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\fintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{62}
\def\fint{\fintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{64}
\def\oiintctrclockwise{\oiintctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{66}
\def\varoiintclockwise{\varoiintclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{68}
\def\oiiintctrclockwise{\oiiintctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{70}
\def\varoiiintclockwise{\varoiiintclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{72}
\def\oiintclockwise{\oiintclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{74}
\def\varoiintctrclockwise{\varoiintctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{76}
\def\oiiintclockwise{\oiiintclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{78}
\def\varoiiintctrclockwise{\varoiiintctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\sqiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{80}
\def\sqiint{\sqiintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\sqiiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{82}
\def\sqiiint{\sqiiintop\ilimits@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  $\forall\exists<>\leq\geq\int\subseteq\supseteq$
  \[\int abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+-=\alpha\]
  \[\int \oint \iint \iiint \iiiint \idotsint \idotsint \]
\end{document}
```

[image: various integrals]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you'd want to use `mathptmx` and substitute symbols from `newtxmath` instead of directly using the latter. The fonts provided by `mathptmx` are in large parts ugly, because they are built from various sources; in particular the Greek letters are nasty.

However, here's how you can do for the integral. I'll leave to you other symbols. Note that `newtx` uses a different font encoding for its math extension font, because it accommodates much more characters than the standard OMX encoding. Also, defining the `largesymbols` math group is surely not recommended, because this must be accompanied by redefinitions of several symbols (or at least it requires a thorough check of the differences between the OMX and LMX encodings).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LMX}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMX}{ntxexx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}{<-> ntxexx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMX}{ntxexx}{b}{n}{<-> ntxbexx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMX}{ntxexx}{bx}{n}{<->ssub ntxexx/b/n}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsNT}{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsNT}{"52}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the OP has an extremely old version of the package for whatever reason and I don't think it at all safe to think that this will work. (This is why I deleted my answer although I realise that yours shows how to get just the integral whereas mine just tried to correct the MWE in the question.)

Comment: In particular, the OP's version of `newtxmath` ***does*** use `OMX` for `largesymbols`...

Comment: @cfr I don't support old versions of packages, in general. In this particular case, trying to go back to older versions is hopeless and it would be wasted time as soon as the package gets updated in the OP's system. Of course the best is simply to say `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` and forget about `mathptmx`.

Comment: Fair enough. But then 'update the package' is a required part of the solution since your code depends on that. [Actually, it turns out the OP also has a more up-to-date distribution. Although it still isn't the current version of this package.]

Comment: @egreg I'm actually using neither, but pulling the best from both. There are some things I like better in `mathptmx`, which I have been using and liking for over a year now, ever since before my [`\mathchoice` question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148740/what-is-mathchoice). I guess I'm mixing for two main reasons: 1) `newtx` seems to be a "modern" replacement for an obsolete font package `mathptmx`; 2) I agree with you the greek from `mathptmx` is problematic, but not because of the glyphs, but rather because of the ill-scaling.

Comment: @cfr the distribution I am using is 2014, but I have both versions of the packages and I was just picking the code from the older one. Anyway I've managed, it seems, to use that integral symbol, or rather get the `largesymbols` font from `newtx`. Now I will consider if I want other symbols to go back to `mathptmx`. For example, the sum symbol is one I like better in the old form.

Comment: @MickG You shouldn't do that because `OMX` and `LMX` presumably differ and so some symbols will end up being wrong.

Comment: Indeed I suspect I will end up only using the `newtx` integral from `largesymbols`, and take the rest back to `mathptmx` style. But that is a topic for later study :).

Comment: For now I have set up my package to use the `mathptmx` math fonts (except for Greek) and take the integrals alone from `newtx`. I accepted cfr's answer only because he had the slot for the `\oint` symbol :). As I edit my notes, I will see if I want to make more changes to the font choice.

Comment: @MickG Just note that cfr is *she*.

Comment: Ah whoops :). Good to know.