# Substitute \frac for a slash (/) only on inline math mode

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I was wondering if there is a way to have LaTeX interpret `$\frac{a}{b}$` as `$a/b$`, but `\[\frac{a}{b}\]` as `\[\frac{a}{b}\]`.

It is a little tedious to change a inline equation `$a/b$` to a display equation `\[\frac{a}{b}\]` when doing changes to my text.

Comment: The best thing to do might be `\newcommand\sfrac[2]{#1/#2}`, then you keep the argument separation, and it is just one extra letter. Actually detecting inline math might be difficult.

Comment: IMHO, the problem is not how to detect in-line math mode (there exists `\ifinner` for that), but rather the fact that the semantics might change when switching from one notation to the other: compare `\frac{x+y}{x-y}` with `(x+y)/(x-y)` and with `x-y/x-y`.  Generally speaking, I wouldn’t recommend trusting an automatic substitution like this except in very simple cases.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti `\ifinner` is not a test for inline math, there are many items in display math that also end up with `\ifinner` being true.

Comment: @daleif: Good point, I spoke without reflecting enough.  A selection based on `\mathchoice`, that is, on the current style, is much more reliable, at least for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Loading [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) naturally switches `\frac` to `\tfrac` when in "inline math" (or text style) and `\dfrac` under "display math" (or display style). This provides a better layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

See $\frac{1}{2}$, or
\[
  \frac{1}{2} \quad e^{\frac{1}{2}}.
\]

\end{document}
```

However, you can update `\frac` to condition based on the style using [`\mathchoice`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148740/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldfrac\frac% Store \frac
\renewcommand{\frac}[2]{%
  \mathchoice
    {\oldfrac{#1}{#2}}% display style
    {#1/#2}% text style
    {#1/#2}% script style
    {#1/#2}% script-script style
}

\begin{document}

See $\frac{1}{2}$, or
\[
  \frac{1}{2} \quad e^{\frac{1}{2}}.
\]

\end{document}
```

Given that (say) `\frac{x+y}{x-y}` will be set as `x+y/x-y` when in text style, and technically have an incorrect mathematical representation, one could venture one step further. That is, measure the numerator and denominator width, and set it inside brackets if necessary:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldfrac\frac% Store \frac
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\groupit}[1]{(#1)}% To group...
\newcommand{\nogroupit}[1]{#1}% ...or not to group
\renewcommand{\frac}[2]{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{$#1$}% Store numerator
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{$#2$}% Store denominator
  \ifdim\wd\z@>1em \let\groupornot@i\groupit\else\let\groupornot@i\nogroupit\fi% Measure numerator
  \ifdim\wd\tw@>1em \let\groupornot@ii\groupit\else\let\groupornot@ii\nogroupit\fi% Measure denominator
  \mathchoice
    {\oldfrac{#1}{#2}}% display style
    {\groupornot@i{#1}/\groupornot@ii{#2}}% text style
    {\groupornot@i{#1}/\groupornot@ii{#2}}% script style
    {\groupornot@i{#1}/\groupornot@ii{#2}}% script-script style
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{m}{x^2}$, or
\[
  \frac{1}{2} \quad e^{\frac{1}{2}} \quad e^{\frac{x+y}{x-y}}.
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice!

Can you just clarify what is the difference between text style, script style and script-script stile?

Comment: @josinalvo: `x` is in display style under `\[x\]`, in text style under `$x$`, in script style under `$a^x$` and in script-script style under `$a^{b^x}$` or higher super-/sub-scripts.

Comment: Mmmh… What about `\frac{x+y}{x-y}`?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti is right --- the problem is that *semantically* `\frac{x}{y}` is equivalent to `(x)/(y)` (grouping included), *not* to `x/y`.  Still, TeXnically the answer is correct. A warning about semantic would be useful, though.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: I've added some flair to the choice, grouping as is necessary based on an elementary width check.