# How to create a dynamic macro to detect if display style is enabled

Tags: macros, displaystyle

I don't really have much insight on how \displaystyle actually works, i just see the difference between in-line equation like `$\frac{1}{2}$` which displays a small fraction and `$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$` which produce a bigger fraction.

My question: is it possibile to build a single macros such that (on input a,b), in line equations produces `$a/b$` and in display-style equation produces `$\frac{a}{b}$`?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! You are looking for the `\mathchoice` macro, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148740/15925

Comment: What @AndrewSwann said. In your special case it should be `\mathchoice{\frac{a}{b}}{a/b}{a/b}{a/b}`. The second and third repetition of `a/b` is for script and scriptscript style, should you need that.

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317272/36296

Comment: sorry, haven't seen that... should i close this question?