# Inline-style variant of \underset

Tags: math-operators, inline, displaystyle

I need to indicate the relation to that the ordering `\geq` operator refers, because there are several relations `R`, `Q` and so on. For display-style math I use the `\underset` macro to put the relation symbol below the operator. Actually I defined a new macro like this

```
% Extended >= operator
\newcommand{\extgeq}[1]{\underset{#1}{\geq}}

% Some short-cuts for frequently used relations in my text
\newcommand{\Rgeq}{\extgeq{R}}
\newcommand{\Qgeq}{\extgeq{Q}}
\newcommand{\Sgeq}{\extgeq{S}}
```

I think it is clear how it works and how it is used.

For display-style math this approach is OK, but I also need to use it in short inline-style math snippets, like `Assume $a \Rgeq b$ holds and ...`. In these cases line-spacing is destroyed because the relation symbol is put below the operator. However I would prefer a subscript to the right of the operator and the same automatic behavior as for sum-style operators. Moreover, the result (operator > plus relation symbol) should still be considered a binary operator and not an ordinary math noun such that the surrounding spacing is correct.

So the questions are:

- How do I improve the definition of `\extgeq` such that it differentiates between display and inline math mode
- How do I ensure that the inline version of the combined symbol is still treated as a binary operator? (`\geq_{R}` seems to be treated as a noun.)

Answer (score 1):

A good case for `\mathchoice` (see [What is \mathchoice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148740/what-is-mathchoice))

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % twocolumn just to reduce size
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\extgeq}[1]{%
  \mathrel{\mathchoice
   {\underset{#1}{\geq}}
   {\geq^{}_{#1}}
   {\geq^{}_{#1}}
   {\geq^{}_{#1}}
}}
\newcommand{\Rgeq}{\extgeq{R}}
\newcommand{\Qgeq}{\extgeq{Q}}
\newcommand{\Sgeq}{\extgeq{S}}

\begin{document}

\[
a\Rgeq b
\]

$a\Rgeq b$

\end{document}
```

[image]