# Defining a symbol that scales when used as a subscript

Tags: formatting

I defined a command by

```
\newcommand{\antishriek}{\mbox{\footnotesize{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$!$}}}},
```

which gives a small, upside-down exclamation mark. I always use it as an exponent for other symbols, such as

[image]

which is given by `$\mathscr{P}^{\antishriek}$`. My problem is when I try to put the whole thing as a subscript, in which case my symbol doesn't scale. For example, writing `$\Delta_{\mathscr{P}^{\antishriek}}$` gives

[image]

with the symbol exactly of the same size. Is there a way to make my symbol scale when I put it as the superscript of a subscript without having to define a second symbol giving the same output, but smaller?

Comment: i'm not in a situation where i can test anything, but the symbol is prevented from sizing because you've given it a fixed size when you pack it in the `\mbox{\footnotesize{...}}`.  try removing just the sizing instruction, and see what that does.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just tried, and nothing changes. The symbol as a superscript or as a superscript of a subscript has the same dimension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of creating your own symbol, LaTeX has a predefined `\textexclamdown` that one can use. So, technically, you can do:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\antishriek}{\text{\raisebox{\depth}{\textexclamdown}}}
```

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\text` will ensure that the correct size is used, while `\raisebox` puts the inverted exclamation at the baseline (if you want it that way; similar to what `\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}` would do for `!`).

---

In general, if you wish to have a command vary in its presentation depending on the location where it's used *in math mode*, then you can consider using `\mathchoice` (or the wrapper `\mathpalette`). `\mathchoice` has the following format:

```
\mathchoice{<material for display style>}
           {<material for text style>}
           {<material for script style>}
           {<material for scriptscript style>}
```

So, in your case, you could supply the formatting (sizing and rotation or whatever) to suit your needs. Here's an example of what that means: Consider the hypothetical `\somesymbol`:

```
\newcommand{\somesymbol}{\mathchoice
  {a}% \displaystyle
  {b}% \textstyle
  {c}% \scriptstyle
  {d}% \scriptscriptstyle
}
```

The above "symbol" definition displays (left is in default `\displaystyle`, while the right is in forced `\textstyle`, for comparison):

[image]

```
\[
  \somesymbol^{\somesymbol^{\somesymbol^{\somesymbol}}}
  \quad
  \somesymbol_{\somesymbol_{\somesymbol_{\somesymbol}}}
  \qquad\textstyle
  \somesymbol^{\somesymbol^{\somesymbol^{\somesymbol}}}
  \quad
  \somesymbol_{\somesymbol_{\somesymbol_{\somesymbol}}}
\]
```

Specific to your symbol, you may then use (as an example):

```
\newcommand{\antishriek}{\mathchoice
  {\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{!}}% \displaystyle
  {\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{!}}% \textstyle
  {\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\scalebox{.7}{!}}}% \scriptstyle
  {\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\scalebox{.5}{!}}}% \scriptscriptstyle
}
```

which displays as

[image]

```
\[
  \somesymbol^{\somesymbol^{\somesymbol^{\somesymbol}}}
  \antishriek^{\antishriek^{\antishriek^{\antishriek}}}
  \quad
  \somesymbol_{\somesymbol_{\somesymbol_{\somesymbol}}}
  \antishriek_{\antishriek_{\antishriek_{\antishriek}}}
  \qquad\textstyle
  \somesymbol^{\somesymbol^{\somesymbol^{\somesymbol}}}
  \antishriek^{\antishriek^{\antishriek^{\antishriek}}}
  \quad
  \somesymbol_{\somesymbol_{\somesymbol_{\somesymbol}}}
  \antishriek_{\antishriek_{\antishriek_{\antishriek}}}
\]
```

Here they are together, to show the relative sizing:

[image]

```
\[
  {\somesymbol\antishriek}^{{\somesymbol\antishriek}^{{\somesymbol\antishriek}^{{\somesymbol\antishriek}}}}
  \quad
  {\somesymbol\antishriek}_{{\somesymbol\antishriek}_{{\somesymbol\antishriek}_{{\somesymbol\antishriek}}}}
  \qquad\textstyle
  {\somesymbol\antishriek}^{{\somesymbol\antishriek}^{{\somesymbol\antishriek}^{{\somesymbol\antishriek}}}}
  \quad
  {\somesymbol\antishriek}_{{\somesymbol\antishriek}_{{\somesymbol\antishriek}_{{\somesymbol\antishriek}}}}
\]
```

Relevant:

- [What is `\mathchoice`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148740/5764)
- [The mysteries of `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/5764)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I learned a lot by reading it.

Comment: When this is put into an environment that does `\emph' the symbol also italicizes. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Perhaps try adding `\upshape` before the symbol. If this doesn't work, please provide a complete minimal example that replicates your problematic behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `scalerel` solution in which `¡` is scaled to the vertical footprint of the `!` in the appropriate math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathrsfs,scalerel}%
\newcommand{\antishriek}{\scalerel*{$¡$}{!}}

\begin{document}

\[\mathscr{P}^{\antishriek}\mathscr{P}^{!}\quad 
  \Delta_{\mathscr{P}^{\antishriek}}\Delta_{\mathscr{P}^{!}}\quad  
  \antishriek !\]%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Why make things more comples than they are?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathrsfs}%
\newcommand{\antishriek}{\text{¡}}

\begin{document}

\[\mathscr{P}^{\antishriek}\quad \Delta_{\mathscr{P}^{\antishriek}}\quad  \antishriek \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution, however, I also use an exclamation mark in the same way, and if I do that for both (by defining the exclamation mark by \text{!}) they are not placed in the same way. Also, simply using $!$ and \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$!$} (without putting it in an \mbox and resizing), the symbols are too big.