# Is it possible to typeset this double-X symbol?

Tags: symbols

[image]

I'm looking for this double-X symbol. Is this available in some package? If not, would it somehow be possible to recreate this symbol by creating a new symbol which consists of two Xs printed on top of each other?

Comment: Are you aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)?

Comment: Thank you, detexify did not find anything unfortunately..

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  this reminds me of the "smash product" (unicode U+2A33, `\smashtimes` in `unicode-math`), but i think it isn't meant to be that.  and i don't remember seeing it in any of the "usual" symbol fonts.  can you provide more context -- source, meaning, ... -- if it's a "recognized" symbol, it can be requested from unicode if proper documentation is provded.  (it's easy enough to construct, but i'd prefer some clarification first.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton It's an abbreviation for the vector (X_1,...,X_n) and it's introduced on page 14 of this book: https://books.google.de/books?id=BM1ckQKCXP8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=local%20polynomial%20modelling%20and%20its%20applications%20theorem%203.1&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiagoCe0vfXAhVJI1AKHVEeAqUQ6AEIKTAA#v=snippet&q=the%20following%20bias-variance&f=false

Comment: Note that perhaps that is intended as a boldface X, but was typed in such way because of a lack of a better option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should define a macro for that symbol, say `\XX` that inserts a negative space between the two `X`'s. This space should depend on where it's used inside math mode (using [`\mathchoice`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148740/5764)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\XX}{% Space between XX varies depending on where it's used
  \mathchoice% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148740/5764
    {X\mskip-12.5mu X}% \displaystyle
    {X\mskip-12.5mu X}% \textstyle
    {X\mskip-12mu X}% \scriptstyle
    {X\mskip-11.5mu X}% \scriptscriptstyle
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \text{Var} \bigl( \hat{\beta} \,\vert\, \XX \bigr) \quad \XX^{\XX^{\XX}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Funny. Just after I commented, that one should use math choices your answer pops up :)

Comment: You should add an additional grouping around the definition of `\XX` for super- and subscripts.

Answer (score 5):

The correct spacing here is to be inserted with `\mspace`, so it automatically works also in subscripts and superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}

\newcommand{\doubleX}{{%
  X%
  \mathchoice{\mspace{-12.5mu}}{\mspace{-12.5mu}}{\mspace{-12mu}}{\mspace{-11mu}}%
  X%
}}

\begin{document}

\[
\Var(\hat{\beta} \mid \doubleX)
\,
\doubleX^{\doubleX^\doubleX}_{\doubleX}
\]

\end{document}
```

Different choices have to be made for the different styles; the values may change if you use a different font.

[image]

Comment: Why `\mspace` instead of `\mkern`?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Because it has a more LaTeX-like syntax.

Comment: In this case the `mu` is not needed (not bad, but not the key part) because of `\mathchoice`, right?

Comment: @Manuel The `mu` is certainly needed.

Comment: @egreg Oh, yes, I mixed concepts.