# How to Make a newcommand to Give Different Outputs for Displayed Math or Inline Math?

Tags: math-mode, macros

Does any one know how to make a single simple command that gives different outputs for displayed and inline maths

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$A^\prime$

\begin{align*}
\overline{A}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand*\simpleA{\mathchoice{\bar{A}}{A'}{(A)}{!A!}}` and then `\[ \simpleA \frac{\simpleA}{\simpleA}^{\simpleA_{\simpleA}} \]`.

Comment: I suggest (as @Manuel indicated) that you learn about `\mathchoice`. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148740/what-is-mathchoice) and its answers is a good place to start.

Comment: Well this is great, but what I need is something that could detect the displayed _environment_ to change the output. That is, even in a fraction's numerator/denominator, characters should not be treated as inline math unless they are not in a displayed environment.