# Rescale integral in display math with nccmath's `\medint`

Tags: displaystyle, integral, nccmath

I want to make the integral symbol in displayed equations smaller by using the `nccmath`'s `\medint` command, which looks quite suitable.

Is there a way to always have `\medint` prepend `\int` *only in displayed math*, but without typing a new command, i.e. `\int` in displaystyle math? Perhaps with `\mathchoice`?

Comment: `\let\int\medint`? But, to my opinion this is not good idea. Beer use original name for integral

Comment: @Zarko: This is not what I meant. With this, you would get the `\medint` size in every context, displaystyle, textstyle, scriptstyle, etc. I only want to change it in displaystyle, if possible. And also, I would have to type `\let\int{\medint\int}`.

Comment: Than you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Aren't you on the right track with `\mathchoice`? Like in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583738/how-to-define-a-math-command-depending-on-its-mode-display-or-inline/583752#583752)?

Comment: I might be, but I just don't know the internals of `\int` and `\intop` and the like.

Comment: You could have a try with `\mathchoice` whose 4 arguments define the code used or the 4 math styles. But the problem comes from the fact that `\medint` is not supposed to be prepended, as it  is a command taking the following integral as an argument. Why not simply use `\textstyle` . Anyway you need it as `\medint` in displaystyle does'nt change the size of the symbol !! Perhaps prefer `scalerel`, as suggested in answer suggested by @codecepts comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, although I don't think it's a good idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\RenewDocumentCommand\int{t\limits t\nolimits e{^_}}{%
  \mathpalette\usemedint{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\usemedint}{mm}
 {
  \gargantuar_medint:Nnnnn #1 #2
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gargantuar_medint:Nnnnn
 {
  \use:e
   {
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT #1 \displaystyle { \exp_not:N \medint }
    \intop
    \bool_if:nT { #2 } { \limits }
    \bool_if:nT { #3 } { \nolimits }
    \tl_if_novalue:nF { #4 } { \sp { \exp_not:n { #4 } } }
    \tl_if_novalue:nF { #5 } { \sb { \exp_not:n { #5 } } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gargantuar_medint:Nnnn { Neee }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$
\end{center}

\[
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx + \int\limits_\Gamma g(z)\,dz
\]

\[
\int\limits_{\text{test}} \qquad \int\nolimits_\Gamma
\]

\[
\int_{\text{test}} \qquad \int\nolimits_\Gamma
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The trick is to gather all possible tokens following `\int`, namely a possible `\limits` or `\nolimits`, then the superscript and the subscript. The whole lot is preceded, if in `\displaystyle`, by `\medint`.

For comparison, here's the standard output

[image]

Here's the output if `amsmath` is called with the `intlimits` option.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you think that it isn't a good idea? I'm trying to typeset a lecture script in German, and in German tradition, we have the `intlimits` option with smaller integrals, as e.g. the integrals in unicode. If you have a better idea (e.g. I've seen the `scalerel` package), I'm very open about it (since your solution doesn't look like it is meant to be done). See e.g. *Königsberger: Analysis 1* for a good standard.