# Macro for a math map f:A\to B

Tags: math-mode, macros, conditionals, displaystyle

I want to write a macro for a math map `f:A\to B` when it is in inline math mode and `f:A\longrightarrow B` for displayed math. But I don't know how to check that it is in inline mode or displayed style.

Here is my try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\map}[3]{#1\mathpunct{:}#2\longrightarrow #3}

\begin{document}

$\map{f}{A}{B}$
\[\map{f}{A}{B}\]
\end{document}
```

I have tried the following but it produces `Undefined control sequence. $\map`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand[3]{\map}{
    #1\mathpunct{:}#2
    \if@display
    \longrightarrow #3
    \else
    \rightarrow #3
    \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Use the command `\mathchoice`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148740/what-is-mathchoice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't differentiate displaystyle and text style using a if test since use of the plain TeX `\over` can change the mathstyle after the fact. But you can use `\mathchoice` to provide four expressions (one for each math size (display/text/script/scriptscript)) and only the one for the right size will actually appear:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\map}[3]{#1\colon #2\mathchoice{\longrightarrow}{\to}{\to}{\to}#3}

\begin{document}

$\map{f}{A}{B}$
\[\map{f}{A}{B}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you should replace `\mathpunct{:}` by `\colon`?

Comment: @Gaussler Thanks, edited.

Comment: @Gaussler: Why? `\colon` is more suitable and recurrent? I use `\mathpunct{:}` always.

Comment: @C.F.G Without amsmath, `\colon` is the same as `\mathpunct{:}` but it's shorter and IMO more readable. With amsmath it has different spacing which makes it feel less cramped and more like a normal colon.