# \vDash and \models but with three horizontal lines

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, relation-symbols

I'm looking for way to draw the \vDash or the \models operator but with three horizontal lines instead of just two. Is there an easy way to do this?

It should look something like this:
[image]

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`turnstile`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/turnstile?lang=en) package is designed for typesetting various configurations of turnstiles with or without text above and below the bar.

For your case, you want a **s**ingle vertical bar on the left followed by a **t**riple horizontal bar, and no text, so the command is `\sttstile{}{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{turnstile}

\begin{document}

\[
\sttstile{}{} K
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of output from above code]

Comment: If you could add an image, this answer would be more helpful.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've done so.

Answer (score 8):

You can mimick the definition of `\models`, but with a slight change so the subscript is a bit lower.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mmmodels}{\mathrel{|\mkern-3.5mu{\equiv}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\mmmodels_K
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A little extension on [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/627957/5764) that scales to the math style being used via [`\mathchoice`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148740/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mmmodels}{%
  \mathrel{
    {|}
    \mathchoice{\mkern -3.5mu}{\mkern -3.5mu}{\mkern -4mu}{\mkern -4.5mu}
    {\equiv}
  }
}

\begin{document}

$a \mmmodels b_{a \mmmodels b_{a \mmmodels b}}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

U+2AE2 VERTICAL BAR TRIPLE RIGHT TURNSTILE ⫢ is `\vDdash` in `unicode-math` for lualatex and xelatex  or compatible packages such as `stix2` for pdflatex

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}


\[
A \vDdash B
\]

\end{document}
```