# How can I consistently adjust kerning within and outside of subscripts?

Tags: subscripts, kerning

I want to define a macro that shows an array access in a language like in C or Java.

My first try looked like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\accessI}[2]{#1\left[#2\right]}
\[
\accessI{a}{i}
\]
```

[image]

I didn't like this because the kerning of the brackets didn't seem right (they should be closer, imho). The kerning can be easily fixed with `\mkern`.

```latex
\newcommand{\accessII}[2]{#1\mkern-3mu\left[#2\right]}
\[
\accessII{a}{i}
\]
```

[image]

This looks great, but when I use terms like this in a subscript, the kerning looks bad again (this time the brackets are too close).

```
\[
A_{\accessII{a}{i}}
\]
```

[image]

I'm now looking for either

- a command like `\mkern` that is context-dependent (i.e. that shrinks the adjustments when used in a subscript) or
- a way to tell in which context the macro is used so that I can use different `\mkern`-calls in the `\accessII` macro

Comment: Are you familiar with the [mleftright](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package and its `\mleft` and `\mright` macros?

Comment: don't use left right, they introduce bad horizontal space https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right/173740#173740

Comment: Off-topic, but still important: Don't use `$$` in a LaTeX document to initiate and terminate display math mode; instead, do use `\[` and `\]`. For a longer discussion of this subject, please see the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excessive amount of space around `\left[ i\right]` is there by design. If you want to avoid this design feature, I'd like to suggest that you make use of either the `mleftright` package and its `\mleft` and `\mright` macros or the `mathtools` package and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro. In the following example, these ideas are used to create user-level macros called `\accessII` and `\accessIII`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}  % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\brackets\lbrack\rbrack

\usepackage{mleftright} % for \mleft and \mright macros

\newcommand{\accessI}[2]{#1\left[#2\right]}     % bad
\newcommand{\accessII}[2]{#1\mleft[#2\mright]}  % good
\newcommand{\accessIII}[2]{#1\brackets*{#2}}    % equally good

\begin{document}
\[
\accessI{a}{i} \quad 
\accessII{a}{i} \quad 
\accessIII{a}{i} \quad
A_{\accessII{a}{i}} \quad 
A_{\accessIII{a}{i}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I marked Mico's answer as correct because it solved my specific problem, but if anyone needs to do something similar that is not related to parentheses, they can (as I have learned in the mean time) use the `\mathchoice` macro that is explained elsewhere on on the TeX stack exchange ([What is \mathchoice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148740/what-is-mathchoice)). For the problem at hand one could for example define

```latex
\newcommand{\accessIV}[2]{#1
\mathchoice{\mkern-3mu}{\mkern-3mu}{\mkern-1.5mu}{\mkern-2mu}
\left[#2\right]}
```

To have different kerning in different positions:

```latex
\[
\accessIV{a}{i}
\]
\[
A_{\accessIV{a}{i}}
\]
\[
A_{a_{\accessIV{a}{i}}}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: This solution may take care of the excess-whitespace issue between `a` and `[i]`, but it does not fix the excessive amount of whitespace that `\accessIV` ends up inserting between `[i]` and a subsequent character, say, `.` ("period") if TeX is in `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle` math mode. E.g., do compare the outputs of `\accessIV` and the `\mleft`/`\mright` approach in expressions such as `$\displaystyle \accessIV{a}{i}. \quad a\mleft[i\mright].$` and `$\textstyle \accessIV{a}{i}. \quad a\mleft[i\mright].$`.