# How to fix the thickness of $\complement$ changes after rotatebox and scalebox

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I use `\mathcal S^\complement` as the notation of complements. However, I need to flip the `\complement` symbol to make the anticomplement symbol. If I only use `\rotatebox`, the size of the anticomplement will be bigger than the complement symbol, but if I add `\scalebox{0.75}{...}`, the thickness of the anticomplement symbol will change. Are there any ways to fix this problem?

```
\newcommand{\anticomplement}{\scalebox{0.75}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\complement$}}}

...

$\mathcal S^\complement$, $\mathcal S^{\anticomplement}$
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to mimic the `\complement` with reflected `\anticomplement`, use `\reflectbox{}` with prepended `\scriptstyle`, e.g. `\newcommand{\anticomplement}{\reflectbox{$\scriptstyle\complement$}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the content of `\rotatebox` doesn't realize it is supposed to be in `\scriptstyle`. So your unscaled version is making a `\textstyle` symbol. The solution is to place `$\scriptstyle\complement$` inside the `\rotatebox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx}

\newcommand{\anticomplement}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\scriptstyle\complement$}}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal S^\complement$, $\mathcal S^{\anticomplement}$
\end{document}
```

Note that you could also use

```
\newcommand{\anticomplement}{\reflectbox{$\scriptstyle\complement$}}
```

Comment: Probably one should define it [using mathchoice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148740/what-is-mathchoice)? While I don't see the command used in display (and probably not text) styles, it will potentially be used in scriptscript style.

Comment: @WillieWong: Might be better just to define `\newcommand{\smallanticomplement}{\reflectbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\complement$}}` for that usage, e.g., `F_{\mathcal S^{\smallanticomplement}}`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple application of [`\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/4427).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\anticomplement}{{\mathpalette\anticomplement@\relax}}
\newcommand{\anticomplement@}[2]{%
  \reflectbox{$\m@th#1\complement$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{S}^{\complement}\mathcal{S}^{\anticomplement}
x^{y^{\anticomplement}}\anticomplement
\]

\end{document}
```

I added a pair of braces in case `^\anticomplement` slips in.

Note that `\mathcal{S}` is the correct syntax. For the particular case `\reflectbox` is much simpler than `\rotatebox`.

[image]